# How to append free space from LVM volume?

Tags: linux, lvm

I am running out of space on a LVM volume and am wondering where 10G are allocated:

```
df -h
/dev/mapper/vg0-staging   20G   19G  177M 100% /mnt/staging

lvs
staging vg0  -wi-ao----  30.00g
```

Is there a way to append the free space and increase the partition to the full size of the volume while keeping the data intact?

Comment: Yes, and it's trivial to do.  From what I'm seeing in your output, you've already added the space to the staging volume.  It looks like you forgot to resize the filesystem that lives on it though.  If you used lvresize/lvextend to add that space, it would've automatically resized the underlying filesystem with the `-r` switch.  How to resize the filesystem manually is entirely dependent on the filesystem that's being used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to resize the filesystem inside `vg0/staging` volume:

- if it is an XFS filesystem, you can resize it with `xfs_growfs /mnt/staging`
- if it is an EXT4 filesystem, you can resize it with `resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg0-staging`